# How prove this triangulation with indentity

Tags: triangulation

> let $x,y,z\in (0,\pi)$, prove or disprove
>
> $$\sin{(x+y)}\cdot\sin{(y+z)}\cdot\sin{(x+z)}\cdot\sin{(x+y+z)}
> =[\sin{(x+y+z)}\cdot\sin{x}+\sin{y}\cdot\sin{z}]\times[\sin{(x+2y+z)}\cdot\sin{z}+\sin{(x+y)}\cdot\sin{y}]$$

if this is ture, we can use this
$$2\sin{x}\sin{y}=\cos{(x-y)}-\cos{(x+y)}$$
But I fell very ugly.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

From the RHS,

Using [Werner Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html)

$$2\sin(x+2y+z)\sin z=\cos(x+2y)-\cos(x+2y+2z)$$

and $$2\sin(x+y)\sin y=\cos x-\cos(x+2y)$$

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) formula,

$$2\sin(x+2y+z)\sin z+2\sin(x+y)\sin y=\cos x-\cos(x+2y+2z)=2\sin(y+z)\sin(x+y+z)$$

Can you apply the same method on $$[\sin(x+y+z)\sin x]+[\sin y\sin z]?$$

Comment: so this indentity is true?

Comment: @chinamath, Have you verified my last statement?